# How to save text files from multiple URLs in a common csv file using a for loop

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I'm using R, I've currently got a for loop to save text data from URLs in a csv file:

```
for(i in 1:9){
    cancerdbdata <-
    paste0("http://annotation.dbi.udel.edu/CancerDB/record_CD_0000", i, ".txt")
    cancerdbdata1 <- download.file(cancerdbdata, destfile = 
    "CancerDrugDBdestfile.csv")
}
```

However, as this loops it does not sequentially download the data from each URL to the csv file and I am left with a csv file that only contains the information from the last URL. I've tried to find a way to add the data sequentially from each URL but cannot. Sorry if this has already been asked, I looked around but couldn't find anything that made sense to me. Thanks in advance for an answer or redirecting me to an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `download.file` has a `mode` parameter you can set to `"a"`. This will make sure that the additional data will be appended to the file.

The following should do:

```
for(i in 1:9) {
  cancerdbdata <- paste0("http://annotation.dbi.udel.edu/CancerDB/record_CD_0000",
                         i,
                         ".txt")
  cancerdbdata1 <- download.file(cancerdbdata,
                                 destfile = "CancerDrugDBdestfile.csv",
                                 mode = "a")
}
```

I hope this helps.